# How to update album art in mediastore on Android 10 (API 29)?

Tags: java, android

Now that `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` is deprecated in API 29, how can we update the album art in the mediastore?

**My Code**

```
final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, albumId);

String albumIdColumn    = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
String albumDataColumn  = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;      //This is Deprecated in API 29!

ContentValues valuesAlbum = new ContentValues();
valuesAlbum.put(albumIdColumn, albumId);
valuesAlbum.put(albumDataColumn, file_path);

//Update the albumArt.
contentResolver.delete(albumArtUri, null,null);
contentResolver.insert(sArtworkUri, valuesAlbum);
```